# Storing intervals in the Lucene index

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, information-retrieval

I have documents with the annotated zones - say, 'title', 'body', and 'comments' (zones also may be nested).
I want to search for a word 'Obama' in the 'title' zone. I can use a SpanQuery like `word:'Obama' & zone:'title'` matching at the same position, but it means that I need to store zone attribute for each word position in the document. Can I just store zones as interval coordinates and then perform queries only inside those intervals?

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are emulating having separate fields.  Is there a reason you couldn't just index "title", for instance, as a separate field?

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed an option. But here's the thing: my index content is specialized, and for each word position several fields are created, e.g. grammar, lemma, semantics, before/after punctuation (some of them are set attributes and are just _big_). I can't just rename the fields to title_grammar, title_semantics, body_grammar, body_semantics etc. - that would cause too big space overhead. Note that some zones can be nested.

Answer (score 0):

This seems messy, but you could store the intervals for each word as Dewey-Decimal-like encoded hierarchies (see my [Stupid Lucene Tricks: Hierarchies](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2019/05/stupid-lucene-tricks-hierarchies.html)), which would let you search for the word in any part of the hierarchy (all text, all of the title, title semantics-only, etc.)